# Pycharm offers incomplete code suggestions with numpy

Tags: numpy, pycharm, int64

I am a beginner trying to learn simple pandas&numpy and I am using Pycharm. Why doesn't pycharm show all of the objects in numpy library as I am typing code? For instance I can't find int64, int32, float32 and such number types. After importing numpy as np, when I start typing *np.int*, Pycharm acts as if *int* is available but as if int32 and int64 didn't exist at all.

Here is a screenshot what the code suggestion box looks like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEHPv.png)

I have the newest numpy (1.18.0) installed both through commandline to the python interpreter itself and in Pycharm to this particular project. I can also confirm that for example *np.int64* is valid code - it executes in Pycharm without error:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.int64(123))  # Executes correctly even though Pycharm shows as if there's no int64 in numpy library
```

Comment: Normally we don't use `np.int64(123)` kinds of expressions.  We make arrays, `np.array([123, 435], dtype=np.int64)`.  We get an `np.int64` object by indexing such an array.

Comment: Yes, the aforementioned code snippet was super-simplified just to demonstrate the issue - that kind of command might not make sense. But in realistic use cases I still don't get the code suggestion in PyCharm, like when specifying datatypes in Pandas _read_csv_ with the _dtype_ attribute.